# How to cat similar named sequence files from different directories into single large fasta file

Tags: loops, unix, concatenation

I am trying to get the following done. I have circa 40 directories of different species, each with 100s of sequence files that contain orthologous sequences. The sequence files are similarly named for each of the species directories. I want to concatenate the identically named files of the 40 species directories into a single sequence file which is named similarly.

My data looks as follows, e.g.:

```
directories: Species1 Species2 Species3 
  Within directory (similar for all): sequenceA.fasta sequenceB.fasta sequenceC.fasta

I want to get single files named: sequenceA.fasta sequenceB.fasta sequenceC.fasta 
where the content of the different files from the different species is concatenated.
```

I tried to solve this with a loop (but this never ends well with me!):

```
ls . | while read FILE; do cat ./*/"$FILE" >> ./final/"$FILE"; done
```

This resulted in empty files and errors. I did try to find a solution elsewhere, e.g.: (https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/249952-cat-multiple-files-according-file-name.html, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424204/how-to-combine-multiple-files-with-similar-names-in-different-folders-by-using-u) but I have been unable to edit them to my case.

Could anyone give me some help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a root directory where your species directories reside, you should run the following:

```
$ mkdir output
$ find Species* -type f -name "*.fasta" -exec sh -c 'cat {} >> output/`basename {}`' \;
```

It traverses all the files recursively and merges the contents of files with identical basename into one under *output* directory.

**EDIT:** even though this was an accepted answer, in a comment the OP mentioned that the real directories don't match a common pattern `Species*` as shown in the original question. In this case you can use this:

```
$ find -type f -not -path "./output/*" -name "*.fasta" -exec sh -c 'cat {} >> output/`basename {}`' \;
```

This way, we don't specify the search pattern but rather explicitly omit `output` directory to avoid duplicates of already processed data.

Comment: Thanks vtronko, super helpfull. I haven't thought of using find. I get the following error, that I couldn't solve by finding a solution in the man pages:
`find * -type f -name "*.fasta" -exec sh -c 'cat {} >> output/`basename {}`'
find: missing argument to `-exec'`

Comment: Why did you change `Species` lookup pattern to `*`? This way it occasionally starts to read from `output` directory as well and duplicates will occur, that's not what you want. Also, you missed the `\;` which is a vital part of exec syntax, not sure why would you remove that.
What happens if you run this unmodified? 
P.S. Your formatting in the comment failed, you need to wrap code in the triple ticks

Comment: The reason I changed Species is because the directories do actually have the names of the species so there is no consistency there. \; is a missed copy part! It does run now, also without the species part. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: I still insist on not using `*` glob, because it will read from output directory too, which will spoil your expected results. If you want to leave `*` as is, then add -not

Comment: If you still want to use `*`, I suggest adding `-not -path "./output/*"` before `-type f`, so it specifically excludes target dir.

Comment: @vtronko I suggest to add the variant with `*` and `-not -path`... to your answer together with the explanation from your comments.

Comment: @Bodo ok, will do.

Comment: @vtronko I didn't mean to replace the original accepted answer but to add the alternative solution.

Comment: @Bodo as I see it, the latter solution is more conforming since it covers all the source directory names while former doesn't.

Comment: Yes, but the original answer was already accepted, so you should not remove the accepted part. It also did match the question. The requirement to have directories with other names has been added later. That's why I suggest to revert to the original answer and mark the alternative solution as an edit to fulfill additional requirements from a comment. Something like "In a comment the OP mentioned that the real directories don't match a common pattern like `Species*` as shown in the original question. In this case you can use this:"